Couldn't Figure Out What is Wrong with My Solution
My Solution
I am currently working on a proof and to express it in a clearer way I used Manim(a math animation software) but for some reason it did not work. So I have to wonder is there anything wrong with my proof in the picture above?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$z=k/(2\sin(\theta/2))$ and presumably $\tan a=y/x$.

What question are you trying to solve?  If it is a unit circle why is $z$ not $1$?

I am trying to find point A's position relative to point B's position and I am working on an octagon the circle is to draw it easier. So that I can tell the software the position of point A and in addition now I am just curious too.

Finally, the only reason I did not say z is 1 is that I am trying to find a formula for this so that you can simply find these coordinates in any octagon.

The 2nd equation is wrong. The correct relation between the edge length $k$ of the regular $n$-gon, the apparent angle $\theta$ of each wedge and the radius $z$ of the circumcircle is $z=k/[2\sin(\theta/2)]$, see eq. (3) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6293 . $\tan a=x/y$ is also wrong and should be $\tan a = y/x$.
$$
x=\frac{y}{\tan a}=\frac{k\sin a}{2\tan a}
=\frac{k\cos a}{2}
=\frac{k\cos(\pi/2-\theta/2)}{2}
=\frac{k\sin(\theta/2)}{2}
=z\sin^2(\theta/2)
$$

Thank you very much but if I were to correct it if I am not mistaking it would not effect y and x which would still be a problem.
